# How to check if a screen session is up

Tags: screen

Is there a way to ping, or check if a screen session is online from an external service like

https://uptimerobot.com/

Would be cool as I run a lot of services from screen sessions

Thanks in advance,
FM

Comment: Are you asking if the Screen application publishes it's `-list` of active sessions to external  third-party services?

Comment: Not publish but make it public, do screen sessions use a port that I can ping too?

Comment: @user535733 ....

Comment: Please edit your clarification into the question. Comments are not intended for conversation, and may not be read by folks who want to help you.